# Hash/Salt in register.aspx.vb or logon.aspx.vb - or both?

Tags: vb.net, hash, salt

According to this site, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288534(v=vs.71).aspx a plain text password is hashed using the 
System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider namespace and "is hashed in the Logon.aspx.cs or Logon.aspx.vb LogonButton_Click method".

The site is outdated, though I assume the technique is similar using SHA512 (not that I will use that particular MSDN example), but my question is why Logon.aspx.vb (in my case) and not Register.aspx.vb, otherwise the new user's password when registering would be stored in MS Access (again, in my case) as a plain text password?

Or should the password be hashed/salted in both Register.aspx.vb AND Logon.aspx.vb? If so, is the code used in both files the same?

Additional comment:

As I understand it, I need to use a Random Number Generator to convert the plain text password, so something like:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Object
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator
Imports System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider

Private Shared Sub Main()
Using rng As New RNGCryptoServiceProvider()

        Dim data As Byte() = New Byte(3) {}

        For i As Integer = 0 To 9

                    rng.GetBytes(data)

        Dim value As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0)

                   Console.WriteLine(value)

                  Next

          End Using

                 rng.Dispose()

End Sub
```

I then need to use:

```
Public Shared Function SHA512 (input As String) As String

Dim input As String 
Dim returnValue As String 

returnValue = Crypto.SHA512(input)

End Function
```

Then:

```
Public Shared Function HashPassword (password As String) As String

Dim password As String 
Dim returnValue As String 

returnValue = Crypto.HashPassword(password)

End Function
```

Followed by:

```
Public Shared Function VerifyHashedPassword (hashedPassword As String, password As String) As Boolean

Dim hashedPassword As String 
Dim password As String 
Dim returnValue As Boolean 

returnValue = Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword(hashedPassword, password)

End Function
```

And finally:

```
Public Shared Function GenerateSalt (byteLength As Integer) As String

Dim byteLength As Integer 
Dim returnValue As String 

returnValue = Crypto.GenerateSalt(byteLength)

End Function
```

This (when coded fully and correctly) would go in Register.aspx.vb and then referred to, or called, by Log on.aspx vb?

Many thanks.

Comment: All you need to do is have *one* method to do the securing of the password, then call it from wherever it is needed. If you want more information, please see [Salted Password Hashing - Doing it Right](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm), and any other sources you may find.

Comment: Many thanks for that, Andrew!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, I need to use a Random Number Generator to convert the plain text password, so something like:

```
    Imports System
    Imports System.Object
    Imports System.IO
    Imports System.Text
    Imports System.Security.Cryptography
    Imports System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator
    Imports System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider

    Private Shared Sub Main()
    Using rng As New RNGCryptoServiceProvider()

            Dim data As Byte() = New Byte(3) {}

            For i As Integer = 0 To 9

                        rng.GetBytes(data)

            Dim value As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0)

                       Console.WriteLine(value)

                      Next

              End Using

                     rng.Dispose()

    End Sub
```

I then need to use:

```
Public Shared Function SHA512 (input As String) As String

Dim input As String 
Dim returnValue As String 

returnValue = Crypto.SHA512(input)

End Function
```

Then:

```
Public Shared Function HashPassword (password As String) As String

Dim password As String 
Dim returnValue As String 

returnValue = Crypto.HashPassword(password)

End Function
```

Followed by:

```
Public Shared Function VerifyHashedPassword (hashedPassword As String, password As String) As Boolean

Dim hashedPassword As String 
Dim password As String 
Dim returnValue As Boolean 

returnValue = Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword(hashedPassword, password)

End Function
```

And finally:

```
    Public Shared Function GenerateSalt (byteLength As Integer) As String

Dim byteLength As Integer 
Dim returnValue As String 

returnValue = Crypto.GenerateSalt(byteLength)

End Function
```

This (when coded fully and correctly) would go in Register.aspx.vb and then referred to, or called, by Log on.aspx vb?